# Inequality involving integral of 1/log(t)

Tags: integration, inequality, logarithms

I want to show that

$ \forall x > 1$; $ x \ln(2) \leq \int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{\ln(t)}dt \leq x^2 \ln(2) $

I've tried tp:

- study monotony of the fuction $\int_x^{x^2} \frac{1}{\ln(t)}dt - x^2 \ln(2)$.
- Think about mean value theorem.

But none of those could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By substituting $u = \frac{\log t}{\log x}$, we find that

$$ \int_{x}^{x^2} \frac{1}{\log t} \, \mathrm{d}t =\int_{1}^{2} \frac{x^u}{u} \, \mathrm{d}u. $$

Now use the fact that $x \leq x^u \leq x^2$ for $1 \leq u \leq 2$.